# Excel365 - How to evaluate index with array?

Tags: excel, excel-365

I'm using the following formula as a sub formula on excel365 :

[image]

when I press F9, then I have:

[image]

The problem is that if I use this formula as the Name Range it evaluates to return only "abc".

How to fix this?